# Rehashing a password being changed PHP

Tags: php, hash, passwords, verify

I am currently having problems with hashing. Heres a bit of background;
The user creates an account, and their password is hashed using password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT). Then, when they login, the password is checked via password_verify and if it is correct, they will be logged in.

However, when the user goes to their profile and edit's their details, changing their password, they can never login again. As well as this, if an employee changes the users password, they still cannot login.
I've been trying to look around and solve this but can't find anything, and what is the most wierd thing is that when an employee (lets say the admin account) changes another employees password, they can login fine with their new password? I've done pretty much the same code as the working changing password and rehashing code, but it still does not work.

Sign Up:

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost"; /*The host of the MySQL name.*/
        $username = "root"; /*MySQL username.*/
        $password = ""; /*MySQL password.*/
        $dbname = ""; /*MySQL database name.*/
        $tablename = "clientinformation"; /*The table name that will be used from the database.*/

        /*This line check if the website can connect to the database, else it will return an error message.*/
        mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
        /*This line checks if the website can select the database the website is requesting, else it will return an error message.*/
        mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("Cannot select the database."); 

        $clienttitle = $_POST["clienttitle"]; /*Retrieves the ClientTitle input from the user.*/
        $clientforename = $_POST["clientforename"]; /*Retrieves the ClientForename input from the user.*/
        $clientsurname = $_POST["clientsurname"]; /*Retrieves the ClientSurname input from the user.*/
        $phonenumber = $_POST["phonenumber"]; /*Retrieves the PhoneNumber input from the user.*/ 
        $clientusername = $_POST["clientusername"]; /*Retrieves the Username input from the user.*/
        $clientpassword = $_POST["clientpassword"]; /*Retrieves the ClientPassword input from the user.*/
        $emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"]; /*Retrieves the EmailAddress input from the user.*/
        $billingaddress = $_POST["billingaddress"]; /*Retrieves the BillingAddress input from the user.*/
        /*Here, each of the inputs are put through the 'stripslashes' function, which stops a MySQL injection attack.*/
        $clienttitle = stripslashes($clienttitle);
        $clientforename = stripslashes($clientforename);
        $clientsurname = stripslashes($clientsurname);
        $phonenumber = stripslashes($phonenumber);
        $clientusername = stripslashes($clientusername);
        $clientpassword = stripslashes($clientpassword);
        $emailaddress = stripslashes($emailaddress);
        $billingaddress = stripslashes($billingaddress);
        /*The use of mysql_real_escape_string also stops a MySQL injection attack.*/
        $clienttitle = mysql_real_escape_string($clienttitle);
        $clientforename = mysql_real_escape_string($clientforename);
        $clientsurname = mysql_real_escape_string($clientsurname);
        $phonenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($phonenumber);
        $clientusername = mysql_real_escape_string($clientusername);
        $clientpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($clientpassword);
        $emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($emailaddress);
        $billingaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($billingaddress);

        $hashedclientpassword = password_hash($clientpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename (ClientID, ClientTitle, ClientForename, ClientSurname, PhoneNumber, Username, EmailAddress, ClientPassword, BillingAddress, SignUpDate)VALUES(NULL, '$clienttitle', '$clientforename', '$clientsurname', '$phonenumber', '$clientusername', '$emailaddress', '$hashedclientpassword', '$billingaddress', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

            $result = mysql_query($query);
                if($result){
                    echo "Successful";
                    header("location:Index.php");
                } else {
                    echo ("Unsuccessful : " . mysql_error());
                }
                    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Check Login:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; /*The host of the MySQL name.*/
    $username = "root"; /*MySQL username.*/
    $password = ""; /*MySQL password.*/
    $dbname = ""; /*MySQL database name.*/
    $tablename = "clientinformation"; /*The table name that will be used from the database.*/

    /*This line check if the website can connect to the database, else it will return an error message.*/
    mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
    /*This line checks if the website can select the database the website is requesting, else it will return an error message.*/
    mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("Cannot select the database."); 

    /*This retrieves the data inserted by the user from the previous page. In this case, it is retrieving the username and password the user entered.*/
    $userusername = $_POST["Username"];
    $userpassword = $_POST["ClientPassword"];
    /*Here, these four lines of code are used to stop an MySQL injection attack on the website/database.*/
    $userusername = stripslashes($userusername);
    $userpassword = stripslashes($userpassword);
    $userusername = mysql_real_escape_string($userusername);
    $userpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($userpassword);

    $sql = "SELECT ClientPassword FROM $tablename WHERE Username = '$userusername'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $datarow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $hasheduserpassword = $datarow['0'];

    if (password_verify($userpassword, $hasheduserpassword)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $userusername;
        $_SESSION['ClientPassword'] = $hasheduserpassword;
        header("Location:IndexUserLogin.php");
    } else {
        header("location:WrongPU.php");
    }
?>
```

user editing their details:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(! $_SESSION['Username']) {
        header("location:Index.php");
    }    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $tablename = "clientinformation";

    mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password") or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
    mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die ("Cannot select the database.");

    $clientid = $_POST["clientid"];
    $clienttitle = $_POST["clienttitle"];
    $clientforename = $_POST["clientforename"];
    $clientsurname = $_POST["clientsurname"];
    $phonenumber = $_POST["phonenumber"];
    $clientusername = $_POST["clientusername"];
    $emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"];
    $clientpassword = $_POST["clientpassword"];
    $billingaddress = $_POST["billingaddress"];

    $clientid = stripslashes($clientid);
    $clienttitle = stripslashes($clienttitle);
    $clientforename = stripslashes($clientforename);
    $clientsurname = stripslashes($clientsurname);
    $phonenumber = stripslashes($phonenumber);
    $clientusername = stripslashes($clientusername);
    $emailaddress = stripslashes($emailaddress);
    $clientpassword = stripslashes($clientpassword);
    $billingaddress = stripslashes($billingaddress);

    $clientid = mysql_real_escape_string($clientid);
    $clienttitle = mysql_real_escape_string($clienttitle);
    $clientforename = mysql_real_escape_string($clientforename);
    $clientsurname = mysql_real_escape_string($clientsurname);
    $phonenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($phonenumber);
    $clientusername = mysql_real_escape_string($clientusername);
    $emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($emailaddress);
    $clientpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($clientpassword);
    $billingaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($billingaddress);

    $hashedclientpassword = password_hash($clientpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = "UPDATE $tablename SET ClientTitle = '$clienttitle', ClientForename = '$clientforename', ClientSurname = '$clientsurname', PhoneNumber = '$phonenumber', Username = '$clientusername', EmailAddress = '$emailaddress', ClientPassword = '$hashedclientpassword', BillingAddress = '$billingaddress' WHERE ClientID = '$clientid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result) {
        echo "Successful update";
        header("Location:UserCP.php");
    } else {
        echo ("ERROR : " . mysql_errno . " " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Edit employees details (works)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['EmployeeUsername'] !== "Admin") {
        header("location:Index.php");
    }
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $tablename = "employeelogin";

    mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password") or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
    mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die ("Cannot select the database.");

    $employeeid = $_POST['employeeid'];
    $employeeusername = $_POST['employeeusername'];
    $employeepassword = $_POST['employeepassword'];
    $employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
    $employeesurname = $_POST['employeesurname'];

    $employeeid = stripslashes($employeeid);
    $employeeusername = stripslashes($employeeusername);
    $employeepassword = stripslashes($employeepassword);
    $employeename = stripslashes($employeename);
    $employeesurname = stripslashes($employeesurname);

    $employeeid = mysql_real_escape_string($employeeid);
    $employeeusername = mysql_real_escape_string($employeeusername);
    $employeepassword = mysql_real_escape_string($employeepassword);
    $employeename = mysql_real_escape_string($employeename);
    $employeesurname = mysql_real_escape_string($employeesurname);

    $hashedemployeepassword = password_hash($employeepassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = "UPDATE $tablename SET EmployeeID = '$employeeid', EmployeeUsername = '$employeeusername', EmployeePassword = '$hashedemployeepassword', EmployeeName = '$employeename', EmployeeSurname = '$employeesurname' WHERE EmployeeID = '$employeeid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result) {
        echo "Successful update";
        header("Location:EmployeeCP.php");
    } else {
        echo ("ERROR : " . mysql_errno . " " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Check employees login (work)

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; /*The host of the MySQL name.*/
    $username = "root"; /*MySQL username.*/
    $password = ""; /*MySQL password.*/
    $dbname = ""; /*MySQL database name.*/
    $tablename = "employeelogin"; /*The table name that will be used from the database.*/

    /*This line check if the website can connect to the database, else it will return an error message.*/
    mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
    /*This line checks if the website can select the database the website is requesting, else it will return an error message.*/
    mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("Cannot select the database."); 

     /*This retrieves the data inserted by the user from the previous page. In this case, it is retrieving the username and password the employee entered.*/
    $employeeusername = $_POST["EmployeeUsername"];
    $employeepassword = $_POST["EmployeePassword"];
    /*Here, these four lines of code are used to stop an MySQL injection attack on the website/database.*/
    $employeeusername = stripslashes($employeeusername);
    $employeepassword = stripslashes($employeepassword);
    $employeeusername = mysql_real_escape_string($employeeusername);
    $employeepassword = mysql_real_escape_string($employeepassword);

    $sql = "SELECT EmployeePassword FROM $tablename WHERE EmployeeUsername = '$employeeusername'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $datarow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $hashedemployeepassword = $datarow['0'];

    if (password_verify($employeepassword, $hashedemployeepassword)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['EmployeeUsername'] = $employeeusername;
        $_SESSION['EmployeePassword'] = $hashedemployeepassword;
        header("Location:IndexEmployeeLogin.php");
    } else {
        header("location:WrongPU.php");
    }
?>
```

Cheers for all and any responses

Comment: Have you actually tested it yourself?

Comment: I've tried changing the user's password themselves and changing the users passwords via an employee, as well as changing employees password using the admin account. I've tested them thoroughly and it all works except 'Wrong username or password' comes up at the login after changing the password. Not getting any mysql errors or such

Comment: The only thing I can see instantly to point out is 1. your using the deprecate `mysql_` functions. Consider switching to PDO or `mysqli_` and using prepared statements. And 2. You don't need to stripslashes and real escape before hashing. Once you hash the string, the slashes and `'` will be gone anyway.

Comment: After testing changing to mysqli, the whole login system broke, as well as this, the removal of real escape and stripslashes didnt do much. Will I need to convert every file to mysqli?

Comment: I didn't say that would fix it. Those were just suggestions. Why?  Because injecting values in an SQL like `....where x = '$x'` is insecure even after using stripslashes and real escape (they're not perfect) so the better way is to use `mysqli_` *with prepared statements* but its not some trivial conversion; it will take time to get it to work.  In any case, I'm thinking your issue could be as simple at that the update failed...have you tried just logging in with the old password?  Maybe nothing was ever updated.

Comment: I tried signed up, changing the password then using both old and new password and neither of them work. EDIT: I could try editing it all to be mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all calls to `stripslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` for password input, the functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) accept even binary input and are not prone to SQL-injection. I assume this already solves your problem.

Escaping should be done as late as possible and only for the given target system, so the function mysqli_real_escape_string() should only be called to build an SQL query.

2. Check wheter in both tables (`clientinformation` and `employeelogin`), the password-hash field is declared with 60 characters or more.
3. If this doesn't solve your problem, i would use UTF-8 for all your pages. You can check your pages with this [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/), every page should be stored in the UTF-8 file format and define the UTF-8 header.
4. Test with isset whether a variable exists: `if(!isset($_SESSION['Username']))`
5. The password hash should not be stored in the session, but maybe this is only for testing purposes.
6. Setting the userid is not necessary: `"UPDATE $tablename SET EmployeeID = '$employeeid', ... WHERE EmployeeID = '$employeeid'";`

And it is a good habit to always call exit after a redirect:

```
header('Location: Index.php', true, 303);
exit;
```